# Unable to locate element with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click on an option from a menu using selenium with Python and I can't seem to get it to work. Below is the HTML code. I have tried Action Chains with `move_to_element(menu).click(submenu)` where `menu` is the `boardMenu-content` and `submenu` is the `boardMenu-reports...` and that didn't work.

```
<div class="boardMenu" tabindex="0">
  <div class="boardMenu-content">
    <button class="boardMenu-reports boardMenu-item boardMenu-itemButton">
      <i class="icons-reports boardMenu-icon"></i>
      Reports
    </button>
```

I tried chaining the actions together like:

```
board = driver.find_element_by_class_name("boardMenu")
menu = driver.find_element_by_class_name("boardMenu-content")
rep = driver.find_element_by_class_name("boardMenu-reports boardMenu-item boardMenu-itemButton")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(board)
actions.move_to_element(menu)
actions.click(rep)
actions.perform()
```

but when I tried that I get the error that it can't find the element for `rep`. I also don't understand though why it is running `rep` in its line as apposed to in `actions.click(rep)`
I have also deleted the chain action section and just run them one at a time with `time.sleep(3)` to give it all time to load and whatnot. Still get the error that it is unable to locate element.

Comment: you're setting rep to equal the result of a click method.  (bool or null probably?)  This button also seems to have no handler.  You may need some webdriverwaits, and then select the button according to it's "onclick" handler.  ("Inspect" the button manually when it's active to view the handler...)

Comment: @pcalkins I don't know much about web drivers or anything like that so do you care to break that down a bit because I don't quite understand what you mean. Also, I have `.click()` in there twice on accident so I edited the code to take the first one out.

Comment: driver.find_element will return a webelement.  However, you've put ".click" at the end which is a method of that webelement.  The return type is no longer webelement.

Comment: ok, I think you changed that line in your post now?  That should return the webelement... but selecting by class name may not return the element you want.

Comment: I have put `.click()` before other `find_element_by_id/name` and it worked before then so I guess I am confused as to why it wouldn't work here.

Comment: @pcalkins I think you might be right but I also don't know what element to chose because what I have in there is all that I am given.

Comment: navigate to the site manually... right-click on the button when it's active and choose, "Inspect".  You'll see something there to tell the browser what to do when it's clicked.  If it's actually the button tag (<button>) you're going to see a "onclick=" attribute.  That will be the unique identifier you want to target.  To learn about webdriverwait, go here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/

Comment: I have done the "Inspect element" and all I get is the code above unfortunately so there isn't a name or an id or an onclicked which is where my struggles are coming from. Thanks for the info on webdriverwait, I'll start using that as apposed to `time.sleep()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to solve this I learned something new about Inspect Element. I would right click on the section I want then hit copy and choose xpath and use that with Selenium. Maybe that is a well known technique to use but it was certainly new to me.